# How to pass data from selected rows using checkboxes from JSP to the server

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'd like to know if there's any way to send data to the server for the selected rows using the checkboxes  I've put on those rows?  I mean , how can I send only the data of those selected rows to the server?

[image]

Here's the html code I use:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="tableheader">
      <td width="10%"></td>
      <td width="30%">Vehicle</td>
      <td width="40%">Driver</td>
      <td width="10%">Mileage</td>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
         <tr>
             <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" 
                    value="c:out value="${item.numberPlate}"/>"/>
             </td>
             <td align="left"><c:out value="${item.numberPlate}"/></td>
             <td align="left"><c:out value="${item.driver.fullName}" /></td>
             <td align="left"><input type="text" name="mileage" value="" /></td>
          </tr>
     </c:forEach>                       
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I really hope you can give some guidance on this.

Thanks in beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

When handling the request use `request.getParameterValues("selectedItems")`. And I don't think it's needed to add `[]` to names

Comment: You however need to give them each an unique value. E.g. `value="${item.id}"`. Those will be returned. And indeed, please get rid of those unnecessary PHP-like braces :)

Comment: @Bozho-Ok. but what If I needed to pass the data for vehicle and driver? Should I also put them into arrays , say ,vehicle [] and driver[]? and finally ,how can I make sure that I'm  sending  only  the selected rows?

Comment: Why do you need to send the data back which the server already knows?

Comment: in the case of mileage,those values aren't still in the server; that's why I put textfields :(

Comment: If you don't store in session, then just get them by submitted item ID.

Comment: I changed the title of the question in order to describe better what I want to achieve