# How to check if a checkbox in a checkbox array is checked with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html table with a column of text boxes (**mileage**), all of them are disabled when the page loads, and I need that when user clicks on a check box, the text box for that column should be enabled and become a required field, and then  if  the user unchecks the checkbox, the textbox on that row must be disabled and the required class removed.
[image]

I already have the function to enable and disable the text boxes (column **mileage**) when the user clicks on the corresponding   checkbox, but it is written in javascript.However, for some reason it only works in IE).

Here is the html code

```
<tbody>
 <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" name="selectItems" value="<c:out value="${item.numberPlate}"/>" onchange="enableTextField(this)" />
      </td>
      <td align="left"><c:out value="${item.numberPlate}"/></td>
      <td align="left"><c:out value="${item.driver.fullName}"/></td>
      <td align="left"><input type="text" name="mileage_<c:out value="${item.numberPlate}"/>" value="" disabled="true"/></td>
     </tr>
  </c:forEach>                       
</tbody>
```

And the javascript code:

```
function enableTextField(r)
    {   var node = r.parentNode;
        while( node && node.tagName !== 'TR' ) {
            node = node.parentNode;
        }
        var i=node.rowIndex;

        if(document.form1.selectItems[i-1].checked)
        {   

            document.getElementById('mileage_' + document.form1.selectItems[i-1].value).disabled=false;
        }
        else
        {

            document.getElementById('mileage_' + document.form1.selectItems[i-1].value).value="";
            document.getElementById('mileage_' + document.form1.selectItems[i-1].value).disabled=true;
        }


    }
```

Now, I know that in order to add or remove dynamically validation rules I have to use: addClass('required');  o removeClass('required') ,but I don't know how to detect whether a  check box is selected or not, and based on that ,enable or disable the text box for that row.

I really hope you can help me out with this.

Comment: why did you delete your other question? It was a valid question, so you might want to undelete it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523127/how-to-pass-data-from-selected-rows-using-checkboxes-from-jsp-to-the-server/4523138#4523138

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in `<head>` or in a `.js` file which is included in `<head>`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name=selectItems]").change(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=mileage]").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
    });
});
```

[Here's a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vG7Se/).

Comment: @BalusC- It didn't work, but I think it's because it is necessary to add the value of the checkbox, because when I created the textboxes I gave them a name like this : name="mileage_<c:out value="${item.numberPlate}"/>" .

Comment: My bad, updated answer. By the way, did you remove the old `onchange` function as well?

Comment: yep! Do I have to use it? if so , which function is the onchange attribute is going to point to?

Comment: No, you must remove it. Did you check the updated answer? I made the mistake to call `.checked` on a jQuery object instead of the "raw" DOM object.

Comment: setting false to disabled doesn't enable a control.

Comment: @Blindy: jQuery isn't that dumb, [try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/vG7Se/) :)

Comment: it works :D You're simply the best, but please tell me how did you get texfield without adding  the value of checkbox to the name? and what does the '^' symbol mean?

Comment: It's the [attribute starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: I added this code to add/remove the class required, but what  if I'd  like to add other rules, say "min" , "number", etc ?                                                         if (this.checked)
            {
                $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=mileage]").attr("class","required")
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=mileage]").attr("class","")
            }

Comment: Use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`. Press `Ask Question` button if you stucks. This is unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a checkbox is checked or not in jquery you would do `$('#CHECKBOX_ID').is(':checked')` that will return a boolean you can use in an if statement

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the checkbox, call the checkbox through the id, then check for the boolean value of the checkbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="sam" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />
</body>
</html>
```

This will return true/false

```
$('#sam').is(':checked')
```

Comment: Ok Sam , in javascript  I used the object 'this' in the enableTextField fuction to tell it , this is the checkbox I want to evaluate. How can I do this in jquery?

Comment: @Sam-But I have an array of checkboxes, would be the same with an array?

Comment: You are somehow going to need to pass the id in there dynamically.

Comment: It easy. Just loop over the array and use 'i' in your for loop to dynamically get the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$("input[name='selectItems']").change(function() {

    var $el = $(this);

    if(this.checked) {
        // checkbox checked.
        $el.parents("tr").find("input[name^='mileage_']").atrr("enabled", "enabled");
    } else if(!this.checked) {
        // checkbox NOT checked.
        $el.parents("tr").find("input[name^='mileage_']").atrr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

});
```